# How to I return a DispatcherOperation<T> from mocked object

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit, moq

I Have a method which return `DispatcherOperation<TResult>` object:

```
public DispatcherOperation<TResult> InvokeAsync<TResult>(Func<TResult> callback)
{
    return this.UIDispatcher.InvokeAsync(callback);
}
```

How it is being used in application:

```
var res = await this.dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                                             {
                                                // returns a List<string> by computing some logic
                                             });
```

And I have mocked a this method using moq:

```
this.mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(It.IsAny<Func<List<string>>())).Callback((Func<List<string>> callback) => callback.Invoke());
```

but the problem with this is the calling method doesn't await for the response and ends up with null exception.

I know call back shouldn't be used to return values, but I'm not able to figure out a return method which can return the result of type `DispatcherOperation<T>`

Here's what I'm trying:

```
this.mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(It.IsAny<Func<List<string>>>())).Returns((Func<List<string>> callback) => callback()));
```

How do I return it as `DispatcherOperation<List<string>>`

Comment: Don't you need to call `callback`? `.Returns(callback => callback())`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have edited the question with the right syntax, my concern is it return `List<string>` where as I need `DispatcherOperation<List<string>>`

Comment: I see. I don't think you can because the constructor of `DispatcherOperation<TResult>` is internal.

Comment: @AluanHaddad so you're saying there's no way to mock this other than returning a doctored result? wait even that's not possible is it

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock a `Task<T>` quite easily:

```
public Task<TResult> InvokeAsync<TResult>(Func<TResult> callback)
{
    return this.UIDispatcher.InvokeAsync(callback).Task;
}
```

```
this.mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(It.IsAny<Func<List<string>>())).Callback((Func<List<string>> callback) => Task.FromResult(callback.Invoke()));
```

It's far easier to mock a general-purpose type like `Task<T>` rather than a framework-specific type like `DispatcherOperation<TResult>`. However, if you *must* use `DispatcherOperation<TResult>`, you also have the option of creating a test `Dispatcher` instance (and doing all the message pumping and things necessary with a much heavier mock like that).

Comment: you missed a `>`, apart from that this worked like a charm, I didn't know you could implement it in such a way, this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: The only concern is why cant I make it generic something like `It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType>>` rather than making it specific to the method parameter type.

Comment: @ThePiatre: I'm not that familiar with this kind of fluent mocking, so I don't know if there's a way to make that work.